# Not Able too see Text on TextView and Button after running

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in Android Studio. I am facing a problem while running my first app. I have created a button and TextView  and when I am running the app, The text I set on the button and TextView is not showing , Instead Its just showing TextView and Button written on the Button and TextView .
Help me.

Here is my code. I can see the text i inserted In Andrid Studio but not after running the app.

```
<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    tools:text="Select Your Branch"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="81dp"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    tools:text="Click Me" />
```

Comment: provide your code..

Comment: Can you share your code where you set the button and textview text

Comment: share your xml and java code

Comment: please read these: [page1](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [page2](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [page3](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

```
btn_cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        btn_cancel.setText("Cancel Button");

        txt_cancel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_cancel);
        txt_cancel.setText("Cancel Text");
```

Hope this helps you. And also check your button and textview textcolor in xml

Answer (score 0):

Use this : android:text="MyButton" inside your XML file.Or paste your code.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
android:text=""
```

instead

`tools:text=""` - this method show text only in screen preview

Answer (score 0):

use `android:text="yourText"` instead of `tools:text=""`

or try this
on your class activity

```
myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
        myButton .setText("your text");

myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtId);
myTextView.setText("your text");
```